# How can I fool the instanceof operator before the constructor call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor

I'm trying to reuse the node.js `Buffer` module to create a revamped Buffer on top of it. the problem is, if I inherit directly from it, I can't apply the constructor and some properties are lost (because they aren't being initialized). The usage on `EventEmitter` works as expected.

I'm afraid the problem lies in the `if(!(this instanceof Buffer)){}` code, that is evaluating to false, since the code doesn't actually inherit from the prototype, so I need a way to fool the `instanceof` operator to make it work.

I'm using the ES5 Class module https://npmjs.org/package/es5class

```js
var Class = require('es5class');

var MyBuffer = Class.define('MyBuffer').implement(Buffer, true);

// MyBuffer.prototype.write exists
// (new MyBuffer(4)).length is undefined
// (new MyBuffer(4)).parent is undefined, etc
```

But `EventEmitter` works as usual

```js
var Class = require('es5class');

var MyEventEmitter = Class.define('MyEventEmitter').implement(require('events').EventEmitter, true);

// MyEventEmitter.prototype.emit exists
// (new MyEventEmitter())._events is an object as expected
```

I'm trying to change the ES5 class module to make it work, trying to overwrite the `constructor` before calling `f.apply()`, but to no avail.

```js
// $apply is an array of mixin'd classes, for example, Buffer or EventEmitter
self.$apply.forEach(function (f){
  var oldctor = instance.constructor; // current instance constructor

  Object.defineProperty(instance, 'constructor', {
    value       : f, // trying to change it
    writable    : true,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable  : false
  });

  console.log(instance instanceof f); // false, this needs to evaluate to true just before the f.apply, how to? instance.prototype cannot "redefine" prototype

  f.apply(instance, arguments); // works the same as EventEmitter.apply(this, arguments);

  Object.defineProperty(instance, 'constructor', {
    value       : oldctor, // try to restore it
    writable    : true,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable  : false
  });
});
```

Managed to fix it with a rather ugly hack, that Bergi pointed out in https://github.com/pocesar/ES5-Class/blob/master/index.js#L24

```js
superApply = function(instance, object, args){
  if (object.$apply.length) {
    object.$apply.forEach(function (f){
      // dirty little hack to make classes like Buffer think the prototype is instanceof itself
      spo(instance, f.prototype);
      f.apply(instance, args);
    });
  }
},
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce problem on Node.js v0.10.18 running on CentOS 6.4.

Comment: is there any way I can "fool" the `if (!(this instanceof Buffer))` part of the Buffer code? The code I posted is a simplified version of my code, it seems that the `this instanceof Buffer` is failing (I'm guessing), because MyBuffer is actually a mixin from many objects, not only Buffer (so they don't share the same prototype)

Comment: Could you show more of what you're doing? The `instanceof` checks I'm doing aren't failing either.

Comment: I created an ES5 "prototypal inheritance" module for node.js that handles the working 'inheritance', 'mixin', etc (available in https://npmjs.org/package/es5class). It works for almost all cases, except in this `Buffer` case, because it got a `instanceof` check. I will edit the post with the actual code.

Comment: @hexacyanide done, put the real code in the question

Comment: @pocesar: The only way to fool `instanceof` is either by inheriting from the Buffer prototype (I don't see why this wouldn't work, you still can mixin other things), or by changing `Buffer.prototype` to something else from which you inherit. The `.constructor` property has absolutely nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Bergi I was expecting that the `constructor` of the prototype would make some difference (like maybe how the prototype is walked when `instanceof` is called), because of `util.inherits` (using Object.create + constructor) on Node.js `utils.js` source.

Comment: Nope. [`inst instanceof Constr` ≡ `Constr.prototype.isPrototypeOf(inst)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).